# how to convert obj to array in Vue.js and failure slice issue

Tags: vuejs2

```
<template>
  <div class="Homepage">
    <Header></Header>
    <div class="blogList" v-for="post in blog">
      <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
      <p>{{post.content}}</p>
      <p>{{post.category}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  /* eslint-disable quotes */
  // import header component
  import Header from './Header.vue'
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        blog: []
      }
    },
    components: {Header},
    created: function () {
      axios.get('https://myblog-database.firebaseio.com/posts.json').then((res) => {
        this.blog = res.data
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

I'm trying to build my blog use vue.js.After get the data from database,I want  use slice function like this  `this.blog = res.data.slice(0,5)` to limit the amount of blog in per page.

But the slice function always fails,maybe because `res.data` is not an array but a json object.And slice is only available in array.

how can I convert res.data into an array so that I can use slice function.

```
created: function () {
  axios.get('https://myblog-database.firebaseio.com/posts.json').then((res) => {
    this.blog = res.data
  })
}
```

Comment: The tag [tag:failure-slice] means something different.

Comment: `> ...to limit the amount of blog in per page...` You should not doing this on frontend - limiting data - is backend's job. See [startAt](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt) and [limitToFirst](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#limitToFirst) firebase query methods.

Comment: `> ...this.blog = res.data...` Can you add to your question depersonalized and minified dump of `res.data` object ?

Comment: Alex,thanks a lot for your advice.I will check firebase query methods.But I don't quite understand how to add my question depersonalized and minified dump of res.data.Would like to explain a little more.Anyway ,thanks a lot!